# ssh command output to save in a text file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

I want to write shell script, in which i am using ssh command.
Whatever output i will get through ssh command i want save this in text file or varibale, so i can use this in my shell script.
Currently i am saving output in a variable , but when i used that variable outside ssh command , value is showing blank.
Code is

```
ssh hostname -c "'
`pwd`;
var=$(ps -ef | grep Consumer | cut -f6 -d' ')
'";
echo $?;

echo "vbar  $var";
```

var value is blank when i print.

Comment: im not sure, but i think this form might help:  ssh XXXXXXX > outfile.txt; cat outfile.txt

Comment: It's blank, because var gets assigned a value in a bash session running on the remote machine (ssh). However, your variable evaluation happens at the local session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To save ssh's output in local file "file.log":

```
ssh hostname > file.log << EOF
pwd
ps -ef | grep Consumer | cut -f6 -d' '
EOF
```

Comment: How can use one ssh for two commands to save 2 different files.       Like one command is ps -ef | grep Consumer | cut -f6 -d' ' and save this output in file.log, second command is ps -ef | grep Test | cut -f7 -d' ' and save output in test.log

Comment: Please ask this as a new question. Thank you.