# bash- Redirection inside quotes after ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

Still fairly new to bash and have a script that uses an ssh command. Following the ssh call, I have the code in single quotes. The example I am following did this, and I have found that it prevents being interrupted by the login to the server I am trying to get access to once I run the script (I only want to access information from the server, not interact with it). All of the code works, except for the redirection, as nothing is being written in the text file. I have added the code below...

```
while read h; do
  ssh $h\
  'for i in path/some/file; do
     temp=$()
     if [ $? == 1]; then
       echo $i>>somefile.txt
       echo "here"
     fi
  done'
done <serverlist.txt
```

Here gets echoed, however, the somefile.txt never gets populated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It shouldn't be working. `if [ $? == 1]` is missing a space, and `temp=$()` doesn't do anything useful. You're looking for the file on the remote host, right? It wouldn't write it to your local host

Comment: Agree with all of above, and am also curious about `for i in /path/some/file ; do`. That will assign the string `/path/to/file` to the fiar `$i` (it won't read any contents). Best to manually `ssh` to remote machine, get your `for` loop working on the cmd line, the surround in your code as you have with single quotes. and execute via `ssh`. Good luck.

Comment: It could be a permissions problem. Make sure that whoever runs your program has the right to write on `somefile.txt`.

Comment: Output  goes on the homedir of user on remote server $h executing your script. In fact, you open a shell on remote server, and your "echo" is executed there. I'm quite sure that, if you write a runnable script (not that one, that is not working at all...) you will find a "somefile.txt" on each server :)

Comment: @Sampisa that is exactly what I found. Is it possible to redirect the output from server $h back to the server with the original text file on it?

Comment: You should redirect whole ssh output, e.g.
ssh $h 'for (your code here) done' >> /tmp/sshoutput.txt
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249945/ssh-command-output-to-save-in-a-text-file-in-shell-script